# Space around disconnected nodes in MSAGL (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, msagl

I'm trying to enforce a minimum distance between un-connected nodes in MSAGL (WinForms), version 1.1.3.  The user creates a graph from scratch.  This involves creating nodes, and dragging between nodes to create edges.  But all nodes that don't have any edges stick to others like polystyrene balls to a wool jumper.

[image: un-connected nodes - no distance from other nodes]

I want all nodes, with or without edges, to have a minimum spacing.  There's probably a simple answer to this, which so far eludes me.  After searching for relevant material on GitHub, here and on Google, I've tried without success:

```
LayoutAlgorithmSettings.NodeSeparation = 200; //works well between nodes that have edges between
LayoutAlgorithmSettings.ClusterMargin = 200;
LayoutAlgorithmSettings.PackingMethod = Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.PackingMethod.Columns;
LayoutAlgorithmSettings.PackingAspectRatio = 2;
LayoutAlgorithmSettings.EdgeRoutingSettings.Padding = 100;
```

Here is the graph generating code (some declarations and other details omitted).  I'm using MDS layout:

```
Graph graph = new Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph("graph");

graph.LayoutAlgorithmSettings = new Microsoft.Msagl.Layout.MDS.MdsLayoutSettings();
            
//add steps
foreach (Step step in config.Steps)
{
    Node node = new Node(step.Name);
    node.UserData = step;
    UpdateNodeColour(node);
    graph.AddNode(node);
}
                
//add transitions (edges)
foreach(Transition t in config.Transitions)
    graph.AddEdge(t.FromStep.Name, t.Name, t.ToStep.Name);

gViewer.Graph = graph;
```

BTW - MSAGL is fantastic!  Such a great tool for visualizing and editing state machines.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same overlap issue. I solved the problem using the below.

Once you have populated your graph, add the node separation using `GeometryGraph` via `Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.GraphConnectedComponents.CreateComponents()`:

```cs
if (graph.NodeCount > 1)
{
    GeometryGraph geomGraph = graph.GeometryGraph;
    IEnumerable< GeometryGraph> geomGraphComponents =
        GraphConnectedComponents.CreateComponents(geomGraph.Nodes, geomGraph.Edges);

    SugiyamaLayoutSettings settings = new SugiyamaLayoutSettings();
    foreach (GeometryGraph subgraph in geomGraphComponents)
    {
        LayeredLayout layout = new LayeredLayout(subgraph, settings);
        subgraph.Margins = settings.NodeSeparation / 2;
        layout.Run();
    }
    
    MdsGraphLayout.PackGraphs(geomGraphComponents, settings);
    geomGraph.UpdateBoundingBox();
}
```

See Example #1 in LayeredLayout.Run Examples:

[https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Msagl.Layout.Layered/LayeredLayout/Run/php-layeredlayout-run-method-examples.html](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Msagl.Layout.Layered/LayeredLayout/Run/php-layeredlayout-run-method-examples.html#0x4d2f34a84a3a595f7050752eb7234d894f72aab7959ef8e69ec4e40aac991da4-54,,112,)

Note: From the source example don't set 'gViewer1.NeedToCalculateLayout = false;' if you intend to refresh your graph.